# Issue parsing JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pretty big JSON file that has a folder, class and object structure that I need to read and export the output to a dataframe. When I try my logic, I am able to get to the first elements but if it has multiple elements, I am unable to see them.

I tried going through multiple posts but had no luck so far. Could anyone guide me on where I am going wrong or if there is a better way to do this ?

**My sample JSON file:**

```
{
    "root": {
        "id": 123456,
        "outline": {
            "folder": [
                {
                    "name": "First Folder",
                    "folder": [
                        {
                            "name": "First Class",
                            "item": [
                                {
                                    "@dataType": "String",
                                    "name": "ID1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Second Class",
                            "item": [
                                {
                                    "@dataType": "Numeric",
                                    "name": "FACTOR1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "Second Folder",
                    "folder": [
                        {
                            "name": "First Class",
                            "item": [
                                {
                                    "@dataType": "String",
                                    "name": "ID2"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Second Class",
                            "item": [
                                {
                                    "@dataType": "Numeric",
                                    "name": "FACTOR2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output to a dataframe:**

```
['First Folder', 'First Class', 'ID1']
['First Folder', 'Second Class', 'FACTOR1']
['Second Folder', 'First Class', 'ID2']
['Second Folder', 'Second Class', 'FACTOR2']
```

**My python code so far:**

```
import json

with open('Sample_File.json') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

for x in data['root']['outline']['folder']:
    print('Folder Name : {}'.format(x['name']))
    counter = 0
    for y in x['folder'][counter]['item']:
        print('Class Name : {}, Object Name : {}'.format(x['folder'][counter]['name'], y['name']))
    counter = counter + 1
```

**My current output which is not right:**

```
['First Folder', 'First Class', 'ID1']
['Second Folder', 'First Class', 'ID2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import json

with open('Sample_File.json') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

final_list = []

for x in data['root']['outline']['folder']:
  for y in x['folder']:
    for z in y['item']:
      final_list.append([x['name'],y['name'],z['name']])


for x in final_list:
  print(x)
```

Output:

```
['First Folder', 'First Class', 'ID1']
['First Folder', 'Second Class', 'FACTOR1']
['Second Folder', 'First Class', 'ID2']
['Second Folder', 'Second Class', 'FACTOR2']
```

Or if you want to just print them:

```
for x in data['root']['outline']['folder']:
  for y in x['folder']:
    for z in y['item']:
      print(x['name'],y['name'],z['name'])
```

Later edit (missing keys):

Note: for elements inside lists (`[..]`) you don't have to worry.
But to be on the safe side, let's say you a json like this:

```
{"root": {
    "id": 123456,
    "outline": {
        "folder": [
            {
                "name": "First Folder",
                "folder": [
                    {
                        "name": "First Class",
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "@dataType": "String",
                                "name": "ID1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
             },
             {
                "name": "Second Folder"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

You would get this : `KeyError: 'folder'`

You could use the try/except statements that I've mentioned.

```
try:
  for x in data['root']['outline']['folder']:
    for y in x['folder']:
      for z in y['item']:
        final_list.append([x['name'],y['name'],z['name']])
except KeyError:
  pass
```

Output:

```
['First Folder', 'First Class', 'ID1']
```

The `pass` says if error is triggered just continue like nothing happened and do no nothing (but could be replaced to do something, the 'pass').

Comment: Thanks @andreis11. One question though - say if one of the elements in the huge json file is missing, say, the second 'folder' element is missing, how can we handle that through an exception ?

Comment: You're welcome. With a try/catch expressions capturing the Keyvalue error. Will update the answer with a sample.

Comment: @Prashanth Added some explanation and deformed json. As mentioned in the answer, for items in lists `[...]` you don't have to worry as long as there's one element. Even so, with the try/catch maneuver you should be on the safe spot.

Answer (score 1):

at the end of 1st iteration, after `counter = counter + 1` statement variable `counter` equals to 1. then on the second iteration after print function, `counter` again become 0. So you have to code it like this

```
import json

with open('Sample_File.json') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

for x in data['root']['outline']['folder']:
    print(f'Folder Name : {x["name"]}')
    for counter in range(len(x['folder'])):
        for y in x['folder'][counter]['item']:
            print(f'Class Name : {x["folder"][counter]["name"]}, Object Name : {y["name"]}')
```